# "that " vs "so" vs "such... that "

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

1. Yamaha is an old-fashioned bike that it's not worth buying.
2. Yamaha is an old-fashioned bike, so it's not worth buying.
3. Yamaha is such an old-fashioned bike that it's not worth buying.

I am confident that the sentence (2) and (3) are correct. But the number (1) seems to be wrong to me. But I don't know why. Could anyone tell me about these 3 sentences. What do you think?

Comment: The term *old-fashioned* is slightly ambiguous since it can have negative as well as positive connotations. You may want to change your question and ask for possible alternatives. Your first sentence is ungrammatical. Can you see why?

Comment: @Mick I edited the question.  I can't see why the number 1 incorrect . please explain to me.

Comment: In (3) *that* is correctly paired with *such*. However, in (1) *that* is not paired with anything, **so** you need another word instead.

Comment: @Mick "Yamaha is an old-fashioned bike that is not worth buying."

Comment: @SovereignSun I hadn;'t thought of that. I should stick to vocabulary questions.

Comment: The _it_ in sentence (1) works as the non-referential variety: <<  It's not worth buying a Yamaha (an old-fashioned bike). >> Compare 'Tom is a man that it's better not to cross.' The _it_'s in examples (2) and (3) have '[A/The] Yamaha' as their referent.

Answer (score -2):

I would interpret these phrases as below:

1) Yamaha is an old-fashioned bike that it's not worth buying.

> Meaning Yamaha is not worth buying, without the reason why, old-fashioned being just a description but not the reason.

2) Yamaha is an old-fashioned bike, so it's not worth buying.
3)Yamaga is such an old-fashioned bike that it's not worth buying.

> Meaning Yamaha is not worth buying because it's old-fashioned.

Comment: Please consider this sentence : Jerboas are long eared rodents that they look like tiny kangaroos.


Is this sentence correct according to your description?  please explain. @Jyphoon

Comment: I would prefer to use the below:

Comment: Jerboas are long eared rodents, they look like tiny kangaroos.